# What is the resolution of the HDMI output on Olympus mirrorless cameras?

Tags: resolution, olympus, monitors

I have an Olympus E-PM2 and would like to know the maximum resolution (and possibly refresh frequency) of the camera HDMI output.

The end aim is to connect it to a high-resolution, high-gamut calibrated monitor (Eizo Color Edge).

I suppose other Olympus cameras (O-MD?) would share the same hardware and specs.

Putting the SD card in a laptop and connecting that to the monitor works well. I'm just wondering what quality I would get if I was to connect the camera directly through HDMI. I was unable to find any answers online and it looks like I will have to get a cable and find out for myself.

I thought I'd ask here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not only one specification but *most* Olympus digital cameras, including the E-PM2, output at 1920x1080 Full HD resolution at 60 Fields-Per-Second in North America and 50 Fields-Per-Second in Europe.

Comment: Thanks. Is this from your own experience or do you have a source of information?

Comment: This is information sent to me by Olympus as part of press material.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did get a micro-HDMI adapter, and the monitor reports "HDMI digital 1080/50i".
That would be a resolution of 1920x1080.
4/3 photos will be using 1440×1080 pixels with areas of black from both sides. Wide aspect videos or photos should be using the full width.

Comment: That is usually 1920x1080.    Check if it is i or p.  p is better.